# Java. TDD. Как сравнить массивы объектов, по значению этих объектов?

Tags: java, test-driven-development

У меня вот такой тест:

```
    @Test
    public void whenRoadGoodThenReturnCellArrWithRoad()
        for (int i = 0; i != 8 ; i++) {
            Board.desc[i][i] = new Place(new Cell(i,i),"");
        }
        Board.desc[4][4] = new Officer(new Cell(4,4),"white");
        Cell[] result = Board.desc[4][4].move(new Cell(7,7));
        Cell[] check = new Cell[2];
        check[0] = new Cell(5,5);
        check[1] = new Cell(6,6);
        assertThat(check[0].getX(), is(result[0].getX()));
        assertThat(check[0].getY(), is(result[0].getY()));
        assertThat(check[1].getX(), is(result[1].getX()));
        assertThat(check[1].getY(), is(result[1].getY()));
        assertThat(check.length, is(result.length));
    }
```

То есть: есть два массива `result` и `check` оба они наполнены объектами типа `Cell`, а эти объекты хранят два поля(координаты) `х` и `у`. Мне нужно сравнить эти два массива по значению координат хранящихся в каждой `Cell`.

То что я написал в принципе работает, но я хочу сделать это в короче, по возможности в одну строчку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переопределите методы `hashcode` & `equals` у вашего объекта Cell.
И используйте конструкцию `Arrays.equals(array1, array2);`

Comment: Скорее всего это не поможет. Нужен hashcode  массива для сравнения другого массива, а hashcode  массива вычисляется независимо от того что лежит в нем, по адресу.

Comment: только лучше не `assertTrue(Arrays.equal(..))`, а или `assertArrayEquals` или `assertThat( .., arrayContaining(..) )`, при ошибке в тесте будет более информативное сообщение